# SQL Monitoring tools Event Based

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, profiling, monitoring

The product m working for is exhibiting odd behavior, we guess its the database issue

we use MS SQL Server 2008

we plan to monitor it by a monitoring tool which is event base

I mean it should start collecting data or start monitoring the data base on events such as

- if there are more than 500 connections
- if the duration of a particular query is taking longer than defined time
- at the particular time set by us
- or only when particular query is fired

is it possible for us to install a tool and get data from the MS SQL Server before the tool was installed??? i guess it fetches the data from SQL Server master table so is it possible???

What tools u say for the above situation

thnx

Answer (score 1):

First of all - if the amount of data you going to collect and monitor is not a big amount - consider to write your own simple service to monitor it, if not - you may look at **Spotlight for Sql Server Enterprise** - it monitors a lot of stuff in sql server and can be fine-tuned about thresholds as good as adding your own custom counters and alerts in it. But it is not cheap.